# How to render full-width japanese digits into half-width digits using html or CSS

Tags: html, css, character-encoding, localization

Hi i have a problem with the spacing of the characters in my webpage after i tried to change the language of my browser(chrome) into japanese. The characters im trying to display are just numbers.

I think this is because japanese language use full-width characters. So how do i force html or CSS to use half-width characters instead?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting:

I suggest that for the number you create a reusable class.

**html:**

```
<div> おはようございます <span class="fix">123456789 10</span></div>
```

**css**

```
.fix {
    letter-spacing: -1px;
}
```

```css
.normal {
    background-color: GhostWhite;
}

.spesial {
  font-family:"ヒラギノ角ゴ Pro W3", "Hiragino Kaku Gothic Pro",Osaka, "メイリオ", Meiryo, "ＭＳ Ｐゴシック", "MS PGothic", sans-serif;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
span.fix {
  letter-spacing: -1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="normal">
  Good morning<br>
  123456789 10
</div>

<div class="spesial">
  123456789 10 &lt;--problem<br>
  おはようございます<br>
  <span class="fix"> 123456789 10 </span> &lt;-- fix
</div>
```

Comment: Hi!, thank you for your suggestion. 
I have tried adding the letter-spacing property on the div, however it will make my non-japanese characters too close. and besides, ill have to check if the current language is japanese or not and apply the fix class. Is there a way for the html to render the texts just like how it renders the page in english for the specific div even if the language is in japanese?

Comment: I think that the browser sets the `font-family` so simply setting adding the css: `font-family: sans-serif;` should render it just like English text for that specific div